# Previously working REGEX match now fails

Tags: c#, .net, regex

As part of cleaning up config files in a build script, we have something like this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(LongStringOfFilecontents, @"Password=""[0-9a-zA-Z]*""")
```

and

```
Regex.IsMatch(LongStringOfFilecontents, @"Password2=""[0-9a-zA-Z]*""")
```

When a match is found, the passwords are replaced with a dummy value before the app is released.

The problem is that it now finds "Password" but not "Password2" or "Password1".

This C# .NET 3.5 code has been in use for several years, has been run hundreds of times, and has not been changed. As recently as a few days ago it was run successfully. As of this morning it chokes on "Password2". The config file really does contain both Password="some arbitrary value" and Password2="some arbitrary value".

I suspected that "d2" might be taken as a pattern, but it is not inside a {}, and as mentioned, it has behaved correctly for several years.

I have tested against a possible timeout and that does not seem to be the issue. I have tried the CaseInsensitive Option, which should not matter anyway ([a-zA-Z], right?) and that also has no effect.

It fails on two different (Win 7 Professional, 64 bit, SP1) machines, but works as expected on an XP machine (SP 3).

Unless this was the result of this morning's Windows 7 Automatic Update I'm baffled.

Here's the complete context:

```
ReplaceInFile(filename, @"Password1=""[0-9a-zA-Z]*""", @"Password1=""REPLACE_ME""");


        private static bool ReplaceInFile(string filename, string regexp, string replacement)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                string oldContents = null;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename, true))
                {
                    oldContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                if (Regex.IsMatch(oldContents, regexp))
                {
                    string newContents = Regex.Replace(oldContents, regexp, replacement);
                    if (oldContents != newContents)
                    {
                        File.WriteAllText(filename, newContents);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    BuildFailed("DID NOT FIND " + regexp + " in " + filename + " Case-SeNsiTive?");
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            BuildFailed(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And here's a small portion of the large file that it being examined:

```
<Kirk Enabled="1" Type="8000" Password1="test_pwd" Password2="dev_pwd" UserName1="admin" UserName2="GW-DECT/admin" DutyCycle="1" TcpPort="10000" ServerIP="localhost" />
```

Comment: FYI: I think there is something wrong with your quotes. I think you should use: `Regex.IsMatch(LongStringOfFilecontents, "Password=\"[0-9a-zA-Z]*\")`

Comment: Is it possible that the actual passwords may have changed to include a character that is not in `0-9, a-z, A-Z` ?

Comment: He's using a string literal, so escaping quotes is accomplished by using a "".

Comment: This is passed in as a parameter to a method, and automatically converted to "Password1=\"[0-9a-zA-Z]*\"" by the time it is used. Note also that it has worked perfectly as shown hundreds of times.

Comment: You are presenting us with a logical impossibility. Either the text that the regex is searching against has changed, or the regex has changed, or the .Net framework has changed.  I would investigate those possibilities.

Comment: ... Your password has an underscore character `_` and your pattern doesn't allow for that....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is more likely to be the contents of the password does not match `[0-9a-zA-Z]` rather than anything with the `Password=` or `Password2=` part.  Most likely there is a non alpha-numeric character in that password.

Comment: @mickeyf - yep, looks like underscores in those passwords

Comment: Duh. Underscores become invisible to me through over_use. Too much code, too little coffee. Almost certainly the (simple) explanation. Let me test to confirm and get back to you.

Comment: Bingo. I'll have to re_write the alphabet to include underscores. Maybe hyphens too. Thanks all for being the extra sets of eyes.

Comment: @mickeyf - try this it allows anything in between the quotes (except another quote): `@"Password[1-3]=""[^""]*"""`

Comment: @mickeyf Shorthand for `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` would simply be ["word character" `\w`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand).

Answer (score 1):

Give this regex a try (using on RegexPal.com seemed to work). I did escape the equal sign.

`@"Password[1-3]\=""[0-9a-zA-Z]*"""`

Here was my test text:

> Password1="Blah" 
>   Password2="blah2" 
>   Password3="045and2"